# Gradle dependency exclusion not working for transitive dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I got the following Exception when I tried to start the server:

`Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class`

Some stackoverflow post suggests that I have conflict versions of spring-asm in my classpath. Through gradle dependency analysis, I see that I don't have multiple versions of spring-asm, but I do have multiple versions of spring-core (version 3.1.4 and 5.0.2)

```
org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.2.RELEASE (conflict resolution)
+--- runtime
...
+--- project :foundation-util
...
org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE -> 5.0.2.RELEASE
+--- com.abc:adcontentserviceclient:1801
|    +--- project :domain-cs-bl
|    |    +--- runtime
...
```

I tried to exclude version 3.1.4 but couldn't get it working. I tried to exclude it both at the dependency level and the configuration level.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'spring-framework', module: 'spring-core'
}

dependencies {

compile(group: 'com.abc, name: 'adcontentserviceclient', version: "${adCsVersion}", changing: true) {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
}
```

Even with the above changes, I still find spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE in dependency analysis output.

Answer (score 1):

The output

```
org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE -> 5.0.2.RELEASE
```

means that while `3.1.4.RELEASE` is required somewhere, gradle is actually using `5.0.2.RELEASE` to satisfy that. So no need for you to exclude `3.1.4.RELEASE`. Your problem lies elsewhere.

You could still exclude `3.1.4.RELEASE`, but the details you give in your question are not sufficient to tell you why it's not working.